# Next.JS Dynamic route static export project opened in new tab or reload the page leads to 404

Tags: reactjs, apache, next.js

I have a VPS with Apache + Cpanel.
I can't configure Nginx over it, so the only way, as far as I know, is to 'static export' first then deploy it.
Turns out I can't access the product page by link pasted on url bar directly (not by click a link text).
The link is look like this : `www.example.com/products/4` or `www.example.com/products/213`
My first suggestion is because I 'static export' the project.

I use next-routes with `<Link />`

My code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import CheckoutBody from '../components/CheckoutBody';

class Product extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
        let { id } = { ...query };
        if (id === undefined) id = 14;
        const res = await fetch(`http://www.example.com/api/product?id=${id}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        return { campaignDetail: data };
    }

    render() {
        let { lang } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navbar />
                <CheckoutBody
                    key={this.props.productDetail.id}
                    productDetail={this.props.productDetail}
                    lang={lang}
                />
                <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Product ;
```

Same question but different problem: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9893

I have tried this to .htaccess. It is not working. I am very newbie to regex and htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

1. What should I do?
2. Is it what it's called dynamic routes?

Comment: you have to change your links. I think the <Link /> is a part of ssr and remember all the things related to SSR in the next js is not accessible in export option cause it is completely static! I had the same issue. Do you have the exact part which is not wotking to share ?

Comment: And something else did you define your home page in package.json?

Comment: There are some steps for uploading your react app on cpanel. Check  the link out. and dont forget to have the `.htaccess` file on the same directory in cpanel https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6

Comment: @Afsanefda edited my question. I have not defined my home page in package.json. And that ```.htaccess``` is not working.

Comment: Dynamic routes are something different! for example when you have a route like: /post/133 . in this route the id changes dynamically. this is dynamic routing!
 
for the .htaccess file it is the same for all the projects I can share mine with you here

Comment: base on nextjs docs you have to use a <a> tag inside the link . Maybe thats why your link is not working. but what I see in your code seems right.

Comment: @Afsanefda That is what I am talking about. I want to open [link]www.example.com/products/4 or [link]www.example.com/products/123 it leads to 404. So, I assume my route is dynamic routes. But maybe my setting is static route? or because I static export the project?

Comment: Aha, I got your point . let me see whether I can figure it out or not.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @ruohola No. The project is abandoned and I got fired from the company.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to using next export rather than rewrite rule configuration. What we found is nextjs router pathname is not populated with the expected route on first hit if you use next export. Until this issue is fixed within nextjs, you can use a provider in _app.js that wraps your components and adjusts the route or put this before the return statement inside you _app.js default function:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const { asPath, push, pathname } = useRouter()
if (asPath.split('?')[0] != pathname.split('?')[0] && !pathname.includes('[')) {
    // Work around for next export breaking SPA routing on first hit
    console.log('Browser route ' + asPath + ' did not match nextjs router route ' + pathname)
    push(asPath)
    return <div>Loading...</div>
}
```